# Плагин магазин для джумлы

Tags: joomla, php

Посоветуйте плагин магазина прям офигенный. Сам пользуюсь virtuemart, очень не нравится, постоянно баги какие-то, которые чем выше версия, тем труднее разрешить. Неудобное оформление заказов, очень неудобная структура файлов (очень трудно что-то найти и поправить их кривой код).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*прям офигенный*" - это тот, который написан ручками, где учтен весь необходимый функционал и ничего лишнего. Есть один знакомый, который достаточно доволен [Magento](http://magento-forum.ru/). Сам не проверял, но может подойдет вам.

P.S. Ах, да... Magento - это не плагин к Joomla, а самостоятельная CMS. Хотя, если учесть, что не только virtuemart - это **Г**, но и Joomla в целом, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: Для себя конечно ручками, а клиенты жадные, их бюджет не позволяет самописный код. Спасибо, попробую в следующий раз)

Comment: @mctrane, а на кой вам такие клиенты? )) Я бы на вашем месте им объяснил, что торговать можно, как бабки на тротуаре, с лотка, как на рынке или же организовать нормальный, пусть не бутик, но магазин. Может они и хостится собираются где-нибудь на ucoze? ))

Comment: Да щас только такие клиенты и попадаются. Считают, что сайт проще простого + балуют те, кто только начинает и не знает стоимости своей работы. Как-то раз был заказ на сайт на WP, вёрстка, натяжка, галерея картинок. Сказал 10т.р.. Так он такое развёл. "Мы отказываемся с вами сотрудничать, Вы не уважаете клиента, предлагаете неадекватные суммы.". Готов убить его был) И всё же нашлись новички, которые сделали криво за тысячи за 3 и были рады своей первой зп. Мне вот в этом плане повезло, первый мой заказчик сам определял цену, очень много заплатил за исправление нескольких ошибок.